Display CiviCRM user data alongside Drupal user data
Drupal 10 - CiviCRM 5.74.4
Using webform, authenticated users can create Drupal content of type 'Post'. The 'authored by' field is of course the logged in Drupal user.
I am using a view to display 'Post' content. I need to be able display CiviCRM user data alongside the Drupal user data. For example, I may want display City, State for the author.
When I try to add a relationship, there are no CiviCRM options.


I do have configured Entity installed and configured and Contacts are enabled.

What version of civicrm_entity are you using?

FYI i have nothing set in CiviCRM Entity settings, as those settings are not required just for getting civi data in to Views. Only other thought is whether your civi data is in same or different database. if in different then there are extra steps which i can't quickly summarise as we have ours in a single DB

This works for me - add

The username of the content author
Relate CiviCRM contact to the user

the latter is grouped under 'user' not 'civicrm' in the offerings. HTH



Thanks for the reply. I've updated my post with a screenshot of relationship categories. User is not one of them even after adding the username field.

Are your civi tables in a separate DB?
